# Show/Hide button when full screen is on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using  **[Angular Fullscreen](https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen)** plugin to make my content go full window screen when I click `Open Full Screen`button.

But I wanted to Hide this button when full screen is on and Show another button `Submit Form`.

When full screen is off `Submit Form` goes hidden and `Open Full Screen` reappear.
I am not sure how to make this functionality. Any help will be much appreciated.

[ I tried to add the example of angular-fullscreen on my **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IbtqOet78EgmnxGM0lQ?p=preview)** but Unfortunately it's not running there for some reason too. ]

**HTML**

```
<div fullscreen="isFullscreen">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non neque eget sem luctus rutrum. Vivamus vestibulum fermentum dolor, ac rhoncus nisi blandit ac. Vestibulum in ante quis eros cursus congue id in lorem. Maecenas ut odio vitae nibh fringilla sagittis. Mauris pharetra porttitor lorem et dignissim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae vehicula elit, sit amet cursus tellus. Integer eu tellus mauris. Fusce eros leo, gravida et tellus consectetur, pharetra rutrum nisi. In dictum nunc ac eros dapibus convallis. Vestibulum vehicula venenatis justo, id malesuada mi tempor et. Nam mattis commodo rhoncus. Cras sed nunc consectetur elit auctor accumsan. Vestibulum congue lectus eu enim fringilla, ac cursus enim blandit. In sagittis fringilla elementum. Cras adipiscing sem nulla, sed congue erat blandit eget. Donec vitae viverra urna, nec lobortis ipsum. Aenean dignissim lorem id viverra porttitor. Nullam eleifend elementum arcu. Nulla porta tortor in risus imperdiet, eu imperdiet risus faucibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum cursus egestas massa ac dictum. Aenean vel nisi nec dolor tempus commodo vel sit amet elit. Vestibulum venenatis, odio eget aliquam interdum, diam ipsum semper massa, sit amet dictum nisi mi in mauris. Fusce a adipiscing libero. Phasellus viverra, arcu a commodo cursus, justo tellus suscipit tortor, quis aliquet urna turpis vel massa. Pellentesque dignissim ipsum quam, malesuada malesuada sem tempus eget. Vestibulum ac eros ante.</div>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleFullScreen()">Open Full Screen</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" >Submit Form</button>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.isFullscreen = false;

    $scope.toggleFullScreen = function() {
        $scope.isFullscreen = !$scope.isFullscreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button ng-show="!isFullScreen" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleFullScreen()">Open Full Screen</button>
<button ng-show="isFullScreen" class="btn btn-danger" ng-class="toggleFullScreen()">Submit Form</button>
```

Use ng-show. Put the ng-click function call in both buttons.

Make sure your spelling is consistent in your functions. Check your camelCase!

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lWjMt8MKX7x68zevMXKf?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesnt is because the preview is not in separate window
Try this code

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/Xg8d2pZlOTGreCi65SND?p=preview
```

**Update

To open the result in separate window, click on fullscreen icon on top right corner of the result area

So, i added `ng-if="!fullscreen"` in Submit input

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="!isFullscreen" >Submit Form</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an ng-if to your buttons?
The following piece of code should work for you

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!isFullScreen" ng-click="toggleFullScreen()">Open Full Screen</button>
 <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="isFullScreen" >Submit Form</button>
```

Comment: Your solution shows me another perfect way to accomplish the output and was working great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've created a different fullscreen library called [angular-screenfull](https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull) that offers angular way bindings to the library [screenfull](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/), which is the most used fullscreen library.

So instead of reinventing the wheel in how to handle fullscreen in different browsers I specialise in how to make it the angular way.

From this example you can see you don't even need to write code (but you could if you want to). You can use directives only.

```
<div ngsf-fullscreen>
  <p>This is a fullscreen element</p>
  <a ngsf-toggle-fullscreen show-if-fullscreen-enabled>
      <i show-if-fullscreen=false>Icon for enter fullscreen</i>
      <i show-if-fullscreen=true>Icon for exit fullscreen</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can make any element fullscreenable fairly easy, and add a button only if the device can handle it, and if it can you can show A button to enter or to exit fullscreen.

As a bonus side, it doesn't even use watchers!